# Can a Batch for loop have an increasing step value?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

This might be short and sweet, but i'm just checking.

Can a batch `for` command have an **increasing step value**?

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set xyz=200
for /l %%n in (100,%xyz%,26000) do (
    set /a value_=!value_!+1
    set x=%%n
    set value_!value_!=!x!
    echo value_!value_!=!x!
)
echo.
echo variable 'value_5' = !value_5!
echo.
pause
```

Running the above code does almost what i need (generates a higher value against each higher variable in sequence). The only difference is that i need the **step value to increase** by twice as much every loop. +200 first loop, +400 second loop, +800 third loop etc.

At the moment, with 200 each loop the output is :

```
value_1=100
value_2=300
value_3=500
value_4=700
value_5=900
value_6=1100
value_7=1300
...

...
variable 'value_5' = 900
```

Incrementing by 200 (xyz) each time. I really need to **double the step increment** each time on the previous value. Adding a calculation inside or outside the for statement does not change the output.

So the output would read :

```
value_1=100
value_2=300
value_3=700
value_4=1500
value_5=3100
value_6=6300
value_7=12700
value_8=25500

variable 'value_5' = 3100
```

I hope that makes sense. If it's not possible, is there another quick way of doing this, or I'm going to have a lot of

```
set value_1=100
set value_2=300
...

...
set value_98=xxx
set value_99=xxx
```

lines taking up a lot of space. That and I'd have to calculate each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set xyz=200
SET minval=100
SET maxval=26000
SET /a numvals=2+((maxval-minval) / xyz)
SET num
for /l %%n in (1,1,%numvals%) do (
    IF !minval! LEQ %MAXVAL% (
     set /a value_%%n=!minval!
     SET /a minval+=xyz
     SET /a xyz=2*!xyz!
     )
)
echo.
echo variable 'value_5' = !value_5!
echo.
SET value_
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure batch is the best language for this?  Here's what you're looking for in JScript:

```
// test.js
var val=[];
for (var x=y=100; x<=26000; y*=2, x+=y) {
    val.push(x);
    n = val.length - 1;
    WSH.echo("val[" + n + "]=" + x);
}
WSH.echo("\nvariable 'val[4]' = " + val[4] + '\n');
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>cscript /nologo test.js
val[0]=100
val[1]=300
val[2]=700
val[3]=1500
val[4]=3100
val[5]=6300
val[6]=12700
val[7]=25500

variable 'val[4]' = 3100
```

Just remember that JavaScript arrays are 0-indexed, where `element[0]` is the first element, `element[1]` is the second, etc.

Comment: Thanks rojo, i'm sure your correct but i've started so i'll finish :] I'm also half way through the www.codecademy.com JavaScript course but when i'm done with this little project, i'll pick up some more JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use a %While% loop to solve this problem this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Define auxiliary While variables
set While=if "%1" equ "While" ( for /L %%? in () do if
set Do=(
set EndWhile=) else exit ) else for /F %%a in ('cmd /Q /C "%~F0" While') do set %%a
rem While dispatcher
if "%1" equ "While" goto WhileBody
rem Original program
set xyz=200
set n=100
:WhileBody
%While% !n! leq 26000 %do%
    set /A value_+=1
    set value_!value_!=!n!
    echo value_!value_!=!n!
    set /A n+=xyz, xyz*=2
%EndWhile%
set value_
echo.
echo variable 'value_5' = !value_5!
echo.
pause
```

The first 8 lines of previous program are described with detail at [this site](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3487). This method may be used in a more general way and it is clearer (that is, for "Original program" line on).

Antonio